# How do I remove a string between a path with horizontal bar and colon (:) using awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How do I remove a string between a path with horizontal bar and colon (:) using awk or sed

Sample Input:

```
"/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:"
```

Desired output:

```
 131300_38153.log
```

Attempt :

```
echo "/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:"|sed -n 's/.*/data/loads/logs/\([^ ]*\):/\1/p'
```

Comment: It's called "underscore", not "horizontal bar"

Comment: I think when she says "horizontal bar" she might actually be talking about the forward slash rather than the underscore.

Comment: Just to be clear: `/` is called forward slash or slash, `_` is called underscore, `-` is called a dash or hyphen, `|` is called a pipe, I hope we're clear now. "horizontal bar" is not a commonly understood name, it's unclear what it refers to. And "removing X from a string" means obtaining a string without X. But here it seems you want to get X out of a string, which is usually called *extracting*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your `sed` is that you have `/` embedded in the `s///` command.
That cannot work, because it breaks the syntax.
Luckily you can replace the `/` with something else,
for example `?`, and use `s???` instead.
Then you can embed `/` (but not `?`),
like this:

```
sed -n 's?.*/data/loads/logs/\([^ ]*\):?\1?p'
```

But this is not enough to solve your problem.
For one thing, you want to delete everything after the `:`.
So write `:.*`.
And, instead of `[^ ]`, I think you meant to write `[^:]`.
This will work:

```
sed -n 's?.*/data/loads/logs/\([^:]*\):.*?\1?p'
```

But why write it in such a complicated way?
Based on the sample input,
you can cut off everything from the beginning until the last `/`,
and then cut off everything from the first `:` until the end.

```
sed -ne 's?.*/\([^/:]*\):.*?\1?p' <<< "$line"
```

Btw, you can do this natively with Bash only:

```
line="/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:"
line=${line##*/}
line=${line%%:*}
echo "$line"
```

Comment: In bash only solution you can even do `basename "${line%%:*}"`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou `basename` is a program, so that would make the solution not native Bash.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`

```
$ echo "/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:" | sed -E 's/(^\/.*\/)(.*)(:.*:)/\2/'
131300_38153.log
```

With `awk`

```
$ echo "/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:" | awk -F'[/|:]' '{print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy with AWK

`echo "/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:" | awk -F : '{print $1}' | awk -F / '{print $NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

try following awk and sed solutions too, which could help you in your question.

**Solution 1st:** using substitute functionality of awk.

```
echo "/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:" | awk '{sub(/.*\//,"");sub(/:.*/,"");print}'
```

**Solution 2nd:** Using match function of awk, which we will give regex in it and then print the matched value.

```
echo "/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:" | awk '{match($0,/[0-9].[^:]*/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

**Solution 3rd:** Setting RS(Record separator) value as /:

```
echo "/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:" | awk -v RS='[/:]' 'NR==5'
```

**Solution 4th:** Using RS(Record separator) value as /: and then matching regex from digits to .log for matching exact word.

```
echo "/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:" | awk -v RS='[/:]' '/[0-9].*log/'
```

**Solution 5th:** Making custom field separator as either string /data/loads/logs or :

```
echo "/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:" | awk -F'/data/loads/logs/|:' '{print $2}'
```

**Solution 6th:** By using sed command by splitting line into multiple parts and keep them in temp memory of sed and printing the 2nd required match as per requirement.

```
echo "/data/loads/logs/131300_38153.log:459:" | sed 's/\(.*\/\)\(.[^:]*\)\(.*\)/\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/.*\/\([^/:_]*_[^/:]*\):.*/\1/p' file
```

Find a string which begins with a `/` followed by zero or more characters which are niether a `/` ,`:` or an `_` followed by a `_` followed by zero or more characters which are neither a `/` or a `:` followed by a `:`. Only print such a string if a substitution take place.